# Testing from portrait to landscape and from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso

I have been making a mock-up daily tasks manager application for practice.
Currently I am trying to test how it works both in portrait and landscape.

However, either my portrait or my landscape tests failed. It seems, even though I am changing the orientation before every test (and returning to the original state after every test), that somehow the portrait orientation is not being recognised after a single test in landscape, and vice versa.

I have been using these annotations:

```
      @Before
fun change(){
    MyRule.scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT }
}

       @After
fun changeBack(){
    MyRule.scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT }
}
```

I have tried placing these code snippets inside of my tests, rather than in annotations, but then I get NullPointerException: onAction is already destroyed...

I have also tried launching actions before every test, changing the order of tests, pretty much everything I could have thought of (btw, the tests work fine if I put them in separate classes). How can I fix this?

To anyone out there willing to answer me, thank You.